# Angular 6/7: Only fetch data from API once but display in two routes / views

Tags: angular, angular-services, angular-httpclient

I am new to Angular `>` v1 and I am trying to get my head around some concepts (coming from a React/Redux background).

I have a RESTful API I want to get data from the API and display it in view/route #1, then allow the user to drill-down and see further info in view/route #2 (using `.filter()` to get just the pertinent object).

However, I find that Angular is downloading the API data on every view/route change. How do you workaround this normally, do you workaround this or is there a different pattern Angular devs usually use?

```
// src/app/core/api-client.service.ts

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient  } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ApiClientService {

  domains;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getDomains() {
    console.info(this.domains);
    if (this.domains && this.domains.length) {
      return this.domains;
    }
    this.domains = this.http.get<Array<any>>('http://192.168.33.11:3000/domains/list');
    return this.domains;
  }

  getHostCapabilities() {
    return this.http.get<Array<any>>('http://192.168.33.11:3000/host/capabilities');
  }
}
```

---

```
// src/app/components/domains-list/domains-list.component.ts

import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ApiClientService} from '../../core/api-client.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-domains-list',
  templateUrl: './domains-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./domains-list.component.scss']
})
export class DomainsListComponent implements OnInit {

  domains: any;

  constructor(private ApiClient: ApiClientService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.ApiClient.getDomains().subscribe(data => this.domains = data);
  }

}
```

---

```
// src/app/components/domain-detail/domain-detail.component.ts

import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

import { ApiClientService } from '../../core/api-client.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-domain-detail',
  templateUrl: './domain-detail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./domain-detail.component.scss']
})
export class DomainDetailComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  domainUuid: any;
  domains: any;
  private sub: any;

  constructor(
    private ApiClient: ApiClientService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    // my attempt at caching (still unfamiliar with Rxjs)
    this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      this.domainUuid = params.uuid;
    });
    this.ApiClient.getDomains().subscribe(data => this.domains = data.filter(item => item.uuid === this.domainUuid));
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.sub.unsubscribe();
  }

}
```

Comment: From your code, it looks like you are calling this.ApiClient.getDomains() in both components mentioned this is why it's calling the API upon route change.

Comment: Yes, that I understand but how do I approach this and not do that? What does that pattern look like? This is all I have seen documented

Comment: If you want the this.domains  (domains) to be available on every compenent you should use a service to share the data between components. https://blogs.msmvps.com/deborahk/build-a-simple-angular-service-to-share-data/

Answer (score 1):

You can use `shareReplay(1)` to share the latest data with the new subscribers. But from what I understand from your code, you want to load domains only once. Therefore, you can call http request on service constructor and then share the data with `domains` observable like this:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient  } from '@angular/common/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';
import {shareReplay} from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ApiClientService {

  domains: Observable<Array<any>>;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { 
     this.domains = this.http.get<Array<any>>('http://192.168.33.11:3000/domains/list');
  }

  getDomains() {
    return this.domains.pipe(shareReplay(1));
  }

  getHostCapabilities() {
    return this.http.get<Array<any>>('http://192.168.33.11:3000/host/capabilities');
  }
}
```

Comment: A great solution for when you don't want a whole store.

Comment: @MarzSocks glad to hear that it helped. Btw, with your response I noticed a typo in the answer :D

Answer (score 0):

Store data in browser local storage after getting them in first route. Then use that local storage data in next routes. (Yes, there is a security risk.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use @ngrx/store. It's the implementation of Redux for Angular.